# SQL Server stored procedures on updates. Differentiate between nulls and not existing with json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

The problem should be quite simple:

I want to pass json to a SQL Server stored procedure.

Three examples:

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "Name 1", "comment": "Test comment" }
{ "id": 1, "name": "Name 2" }
{ "id": 1, "comment": null }
```

- #2 to update the name without touching the comment
- #3 to null the comment without touching the name

Is something like that possible? Or what are the alternatives using stored procedures for updates?

Comment: Based on the question title, have you read the [json_value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql) and [json_query()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql) documentation and the differences between lax mode and strict mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can also query your data `FROM OPENJSON(...)` and filter with `WHERE` to select the value of each property. It does not return what does not exist.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=89ae6f0923592bee72b18a09573bba49).

```
declare @j nvarchar(max) = N'[{ "id": 1, "name": "Name 1", "comment": "Test comment" },
{ "id": 1, "name": "Name 2" },
{ "id": 1, "comment": null }]'

select
  j.[key],
  jsub.*
from openjson(@j) j
  cross apply (
    select *
    from openjson(j.[value])
  ) jsub

| key | key     | value        | type |
+-----+---------+--------------+------+
| 0   | id      | 1            | 2    |
| 0   | name    | Name 1       | 1    |
| 0   | comment | Test comment | 1    |
| 1   | id      | 1            | 2    |
| 1   | name    | Name 2       | 1    |
| 2   | id      | 1            | 2    |
| 2   | comment |              | 0    |
```

Then you can use `MERGE` statement.
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c62bc988a4685ac43e84c4f95006fe7a)

```
create procedure p_merge (@j nvarchar(max))
as
begin

  merge into comments as t
  using (
    select
      max(case [key] when 'id' then value end) as id,
      max(case [key] when 'name' then value end) as name,
      max(case [key] when 'comment' then value end) as comment,
      max(case [key] when 'id' then flag end) as id_upd,
      max(case [key] when 'name' then flag end) as name_upd,
      max(case [key] when 'comment' then flag end) as comment_upd
    from (
      select j.*, 1 as flag
      from openjson(@j) as j
    ) as p
  ) as s
    on s.id = t.id
  when matched then update
    set name = case when s.name_upd = 1 then s.name else t.name end,
        comment = case when s.comment_upd = 1 then s.comment else t.comment end
  when not matched then insert
    values(s.id, s.name, s.comment)
  ;

end;
```